# How can I suppress Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willSetProperty` on App.Model while in state root.loaded.updated.inFlight?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building a podcast listening app using Ember.js and Rails.

My `Episode` model has a property `current_position` which is used to display the current listening position of the episode in the UI, and to resume the episode from it's last position when the page is refreshed.

I update the `current_position` on each `durrationchange` event from the audio element, but I don't want to save the change to the server each time so I'm using `Ember.run.throttle` to limit calls to save to once every ten seconds.

The `durrationchange` event occurs faster than my server responds to the save request so calling `set` on the model throws an error because the model is marked `inFlight`.

I've thought of two ways to suppress the error: catching it, or only updating the model when `isSaving` is false.

Catching the error seems preferable because skipping updates when `isSaving` is true could cause the progress bar to stutter, especially if the server is down or slow.

I've heard that catching errors is expensive, is this true? Is there a method that saves a model and immediate marks it clean without waiting for the servers response?

EDIT: I've added the code.

```
App.Episode = DS.Model.extend
  episode_data:     DS.belongsTo 'App.EpisodeData', async: true

  current_position: ( (key, current_position) ->
    # Setter
    if (current_position != undefined)
      return this.create_or_update_episode_data(key, current_position)
    # Getter
    else
      return this.get('episode_data.current_position') || 0
  ).property('episode_data.current_position')

  create_or_update_episode_data: (key, value) ->
    episode_data = this.get('episode_data')

    # Create episode_data if it doesn't exist
    unless episode_data
      episode_data = Buzz.EpisodeData.createRecord(episode: this)

    episode_data.set(key, value)
    Ember.run.throttle this, 'save_episode_data', 10000

    return episode_data.get(key)

  # I think Ember.run.throttle can only be called on named functions,
  # which is why this exists.
  save_episode_data: () ->
    this.get('episode_data').save()
```

The first time `episode.set('current_position', current_position)` is called
the `episode`'s `episode_data` will be created, or updated, then saved.

If it is called again within 10 seconds `current_position` will be updated, but it will not be saved because `Ember.run.throttle` will prevent the call to `save_episode_data`. If this second call happens before the server responds to the first call `this.set(key, value)` causes the error.

Comment: I think you should set the property, but defer the save part. Even better, if we recognise that client and server will always be in sync, the best we can do is to minimize that gap (e.g. if they close the browser, the current_position is close enough, but not exact). I would think that a tolerance of 2-3 seconds might be enough, but it depends on your requirements. If that's fine, updating the currentPosition directly without doing through the model might work just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by updating cuttentPosition directly.

Comment: I mean, making a server call directly (without ember-data) that will remember the position at that point in time.

Comment: So instead of using Ember's `model.save()` method I should use ajax calls to save the `current_position`?

Comment: Yes so you have more control about when that happens